# Can I refer to the object within jQuery chain using this keyword?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I need to increment a numeric character in a `<p>` tag. Is that possible to use something like this below ?

```
$('p').text(parseInt("THIS") + 1);
```

it doesn't seem that `this` refers to the same object when I for example do the below:

```
$('p').text($(this).height()); //prints 731
$('p').text($(this).text()); //changes to blank
```

Comment: The 731 is for height not text(), text could be blank if height is 731

Comment: @Adil the text wasn't blank, I've used the height to examine the this value as I set the <p> as block element and height to 100px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use the anonymous function:

```
$('p').text(function(i, t) {
    // i is the index of the element amongst the collection,
    // t is the text if the element.
    // assuming that the first text-character is a valid number:
    return parseInt(t, 10) + 1;
});
```

Comment: The function doesn't have to be anonymous.